# Finding shape of saved numpy array (.npy or .npz) without loading into memory

Tags: python, numpy, io

I have a huge compressed numpy array saved to disk (~20gb in memory, much less when compressed). I need to know the shape of this array, but I do not have the available memory to load it. How can I find the shape of the numpy array without loading it into memory?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This does it:

```
import numpy as np
import zipfile

def npz_headers(npz):
    """Takes a path to an .npz file, which is a Zip archive of .npy files.
    Generates a sequence of (name, shape, np.dtype).
    """
    with zipfile.ZipFile(npz) as archive:
        for name in archive.namelist():
            if not name.endswith('.npy'):
                continue

            npy = archive.open(name)
            version = np.lib.format.read_magic(npy)
            shape, fortran, dtype = np.lib.format._read_array_header(npy, version)
            yield name[:-4], shape, dtype
```

Comment: This answer is perfect and should really be the accepted one...

Answer (score 8):

Opening the file in `mmap_mode` might do the trick.

> ```
>     If not None, then memory-map the file, using the given mode
>     (see `numpy.memmap` for a detailed description of the modes).
>     A memory-mapped array is kept on disk. However, it can be accessed
>     and sliced like any ndarray.  Memory mapping is especially useful for
>     accessing small fragments of large files without reading the entire
>     file into memory.
> ```

It is also possible to read the header block without reading the data buffer, but that requires digging further into the underlying `lib/npyio/format` code.  I explored that in a recent SO question about storing multiple arrays in a single file (and reading them).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35752728/901925

Comment: This works for .npy but not .npz.  I don't think mmap is at all useful with .npz--certainly not if the data are compressed aka `np.savez_compressed()`.

Comment: Doing any of this with the `npz` archive will require digging into that branch of the loader,  `np.lib.npyio.NpzFile`. Key file format information is in `np.lib.npyio.format`

Comment: Indeed.  I've implemented it in an answer here.