# Append multiple numpy files to one big numpy file in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to put many numpy files to get one big numpy file, I tried to follow this link [Python append multiple files in given order to one big file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509872/python-append-multiple-files-in-given-order-to-one-big-file) and this is what I did:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import os, sys

#Read in list of files. You might want to look into os.listdir()

path= "/home/user/Desktop/ALLMyTraces.npy/test"
#Test folder contains all my numpy file traces
traces= os.listdir(path)

# Create new File
f = open("/home/user/Desktop/ALLMyTraces.npy", "w")

for j,trace in enumerate(traces):

    # Find the path of the file
    filepath = os.path.join(path, trace)

    # Load file
    dataArray= np.load(filepath)
    f.write(dataArray)
```

File is created, and to verify that I have the good contents, I used this code:

```
import numpy as np
dataArray= np.load(r'/home/user/Desktop/ALLMyTraces.npy')
print(dataArray)
```

This error is produced as a result:

```
 dataArray= np.load(r'/home/user/Desktop/ALLMyTraces.npy')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 401, in load
    "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
IOError: Failed to interpret file '/home/user/Desktop/ALLMyTraces.npy' as a pickle
```

I don't know really the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) or [numpy.savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) to create pickled .npy or .npz binary files. Only those file can be read by [numpy.load()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html). Since you are creating a text file using f.write(dataArray), np.load() is failing with the above mentioned error

Here is a sample

```
fpath ="path to big file"
npyfilespath ='path to nympy files to be merged '   
os.chdir(npyfilespath)

with open(fpath, 'wb') as f_handle:
    for npfile in glob.glob("*.npy"):

        # Find the path of the file
        filepath = os.path.join(path, npfile)
        print filepath
        # Load file
        dataArray= np.load(filepath)
        print dataArray
        np.save(f_handle,dataArray)
dataArray= np.load(fpath)
print dataArray
```

Just found that there is something really interesting in numpy load. It wont load all append arrays at once :). Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35752728/6626530) for more info.

This means , if you want to read all appended arrays , you need to load them multiple times.

```
f = open(fpath, 'rb')
dataArray= np.load(f) #loads first array
print dataArray
dataArray= np.load(f)  #loads Second array
print dataArray
dataArray= np.load(f) #loads Third array
print dataArray
```

Comment: It gives me this answer: <closed file '<uninitialized file>', mode '<uninitialized file>' at 0x7f3ed40e48a0>

Comment: I dont see any issue

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but in this cas the file saves only the content of the last file.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? it should be saving the data from all  npy files in that directory

Comment: I don't understand those tow files : with open(fpath, 'wb') as f_handle:
    for npfile in glob.glob("*.npy"): do you mean by the fpath: the path of the big  file ??

Comment: Dear @Shijo, after updating my code, the big file just put for me the laste trace.  Ps: I am sorry for the  late answer , i was so ill alll the weekend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204368/how-to-append-many-numpy-files-into-one-numpy-file-in-python, I  had already put it in this question, I  didn't think  that you will answer me, thank you very much, you are very kind really,  thank you

Comment: Dear @Shijo , I had already putmy code in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204368/how-to-append-many-numpy-files-into-one-numpy-file-in-python,  I didn't think that you will answer me, thank you very much, you are very kind really, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`np.save` writes a metablock (with shape and dtype kinds of information) and a data block.  `np.load` is the complement, capable of reading that format.

```
dataArray= np.load(filepath)
```

`dataArray` is now an array in memory, just like the original array. It is not a direct image of the `filepath` contents.

```
f.write(dataArray)
```

I'm not even sure what this writes to file; it certainly isn't `save/load` compatible.  So your general Python file link is sending you off in the wrong direction.

There are two straight forward ways of saving multiple arrays in one file:

- concatentate the arrays into one larger array, and save that.  This requires dimensional compatibility.
- `np.savez` saves multiple arrays to a `zip` archive.  That is each array is saved to an `npy` file, and those are all collected into the archive.  `np.load` is capable of loading such an `npz` archive (but read what it says about lazy load).

There are some variations on this.  You could roll your own archive with outside tools.  You could also create complex object type arrays, which `np.save/load` can handle.  It reverts to `pickle` if elements can't be saved in the ordinary manner.  In fact you could use `pickle` to save multiple arrays.

There have also been SO discussions about repeatedly using `np.save` to the same file.  That's not hard to do, but doing the `load` is trickier.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35752728/901925