# How to plot an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I follow this links [How to append many numpy files into one numpy file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204368/how-to-append-many-numpy-files-into-one-numpy-file-in-python/42209244?noredirect=1#comment71580639_42209244) to put all my numpy files in one file. 
Now, I need to plot my file which contains many arrays, each  array contain some float number: this is my final code to append arrays in one big array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import glob
import os, sys
fpath ="/home/user/Desktop/OutFileTraces.npy"
npyfilespath="/home/user/Desktop/test"   
os.chdir(npyfilespath)
npfiles= glob.glob("*.npy")
npfiles.sort()
all_arrays = []
with open(fpath,'ab') as f_handle:
    for npfile in npfiles:
        #Find the path of the file and Load file
        all_arrays.append(np.load(os.path.join(npyfilespath, npfile)))        
    np.save(f_handle, all_arrays)
    data = np.load(fpath)
    print data
```

This code gives me results like this:

```
[[[[-0.00824758 -0.0081808  -0.00811402 ..., -0.0077236  -0.00765425
    -0.00762086]]]


 [[[-0.00141527 -0.00160791 -0.00176716 ..., -0.00821419 -0.00822446
    -0.0082296 ]]]


 [[[ 0.01028957  0.01005326  0.0098298  ..., -0.01043341 -0.01050019
    -0.01059523]]]


 ..., 
 [[[ 0.00614908  0.00581004  0.00549154 ..., -0.00814741 -0.00813457
    -0.00809347]]]


 [[[-0.00291786 -0.00309509 -0.00329287 ..., -0.00809861 -0.00797789
    -0.00784175]]]


 [[[-0.00379887 -0.00410453 -0.00438963 ..., -0.03497837 -0.0353842
    -0.03575151]]]]
```

I need to plot the plot the final file OutFileTraces.npy which contains the big array. For that I use this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
dataArray1= np.load(r'/home/user/Desktop/OutFileTraces.npy')
print(dataArray1)
plt.plot(dataArray1.T )
plt.show()
```

It gives me this error:

> raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D") ValueError: x
>   and y can be no greater than 2-D

All that values represents the y_axe, however my x-axe  represents points from 1 to 8000. So, as I understand,in order to plot my final big array, it must looks like this (The difference is on `[]`):

```
[[-0.00824758 -0.0081808  -0.00811402 ..., -0.0077236  -0.00765425


     -0.00762086]


     [-0.00141527 -0.00160791 -0.00176716 ..., -0.00821419 -0.00822446
        -0.0082296 ]


     [ 0.01028957  0.01005326  0.0098298  ..., -0.01043341 -0.01050019
        -0.01059523]


     ..., 
     [0.00614908  0.00581004  0.00549154 ..., -0.00814741 -0.00813457
        -0.00809347]


     [-0.00291786 -0.00309509 -0.00329287 ..., -0.00809861 -0.00797789
        -0.00784175]


     [-0.00379887 -0.00410453 -0.00438963 ..., -0.03497837 -0.0353842
        -0.03575151]]
```

I can easily plot this file.

So I can't really understand the problem.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: What does each array represent?  For a flat plot you would normally have the points x and y.  How does your data map to x and y?

Comment: @James, each array represents one trace, and I am able to plot all them in one figure. also I am able to plot every trace in a different figure, but  when I try to put all traces in one file, I was blocked and it  makes that error.

Comment: Can you please pare this down a bit, and provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @not_a_robot, could you please take a look in the updated question.

Comment: Looks like your array is 4d.  What is `data.shape`?

Comment: @hpaulj, Thank you very much hpaulj, that is my problem, I don't know how to resolve it, because in each trace I have only one type of data.

Comment: @hpaulj, I find data.shape is  (100, 1, 1, 8000)

Comment: Each trace must have data.shape(1,8000)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you give a 2D array to the [plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) function of matplotlib it will assume the columns to be lines:

> If x and/or y is 2-dimensional, then the corresponding columns will
>   be plotted.

In your case your shape is not accepted (100, 1, 1, 8000). As so you can using numpy [squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to solve the problem quickly:

> **np.squeez doc:** Remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randint(3, 7, (10, 1, 1, 80))
newdata = np.squeeze(data) # Shape is now: (10, 80)
plt.plot(newdata) # plotting by columns
plt.show()
```

But notice that 100 sets of 80 000 points is a lot of data for matplotlib. I would recommend that you look for an alternative. The result of the code example (run in [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/)) is:

[image: Jupyter matplotlib plot]